# Pandas Merging Mismatch: Second dataframe never merges?

Tags: python, pandas

I've two dataframes X and Y of 10 columns each. The first column of both dataframes are the same,called A. I want to merge the data in X and Y on the column A, and tried doing the below:

```
Z = X.merge(Y, on = 'A')

X

A  B  C  D  E  F  G
0  y  z  a  b  c  d
3  k  l  m  n  o  p
7  o  p  q  r  s  t



Y
A  H  J  K  L  M  N
0  1  2  3  4  5  6
7  8  9  1  4  5  7
3  1  2  3  4  5  6

Z

A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  J  K  L  M  N
0  y  z  a  b  c  d  1  2  3  4  5  6
3  k  l  m  n  o  p  8  9  1  4  5  7
7  o  p  q  r  s  t  1  2  3  4  5  6

expected:
Z

A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  J  K  L  M  N
0  y  z  a  b  c  d  1  2  3  4  5  6
3  k  l  m  n  o  p  1  2  3  4  5  6
7  o  p  q  r  s  t  8  9  1  4  5  7
```

The values in X perfectly merge and align with A whereas the half of Y is just there as it was and doesn't merge at all. Why is this happening?

In my real table, all the values are integers, so the data type isn't an issue (I used decoy characters for the example)

Comment: It would be helpful to include the dataframes.

Comment: The words concatenated and merge are ambiguous. You need to show an example to be clear. Please read [mcve]. What you tried should work. The problem probably lies with your interpretation. Please [edit] your question to make it more clear and I’m certain you’ll get your answer.

Comment: `pd.merge(x,y, on='A', how='inner')`

Comment: @piRSquared please refer the example i've shown?

Comment: Is Z your desired output?

Comment: @user3483203 i added an expected one too, just now. The row containing 7 in the first dataframe didn't go through the merge at all

Comment: When I run this, I get your expected output.

Comment: @user3483203 I'm supposed to, but whenever I try it on my machine I just never get it for some reason